# Parsing Character Stream

Tags: java

I am getting a continuous stream of characters which I have moved into a flat file in a single line. Now these characters are coming in below form.

```
keepalivekeep_aliveenroll,10.213.17.4,0,12,594,4,5,METRO-A,1enroll,10.213.17.4,0,13,594,4,5,METRO-B,1clear,10.213.17.4,0,14,100010934,1323168443
```

What i want is to move messages coming between particular tags (`keep_alive`, `clear`, `enroll`, etc.) in different lines. For example output from above should be:

```
keep_alive      
keep_alive                                                                        enroll,10.213.17.4,0,12,594,4,5,METRO-A,1
enroll,10.213.17.4,0,13,594,4,5,METRO-B,1
clear,10.213.17.4,0,14,100010934,1323168443
```

What is the best way to do this in Java? What is noteworthy here is that file is getting continuous data and I need to do this continuously in some kind of loop.

Comment: A hundred ways to do it, all requiring programming.  You might be able to employ "regular expressions" to do some of the work.

Comment: Thanks, was trying to understand if there exists some API/ or the best approach to do it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support asynchronous file manipulation. In other words, if you change a file while you already have the file open in a `File` object, any changes you make to the file without opening a new `File` object will be disregarded. I would recommend writing your data to a `stream` instead, something like a `StringBuffer` (gasp, I hate those) would work here.

In short: You can't do what you want to do the way you are doing it.

Comment: thanks Jon , I really dont need to put it in a file I just did to dump the data. I think what i need to do is to convert stream of characters to string and then check for matches.

Comment: That would work, but if you want continuous input you need to use a buffer of some sort. That way you can manage whats coming in while its coming in instead of waiting for an entire line to be written.